# Are there any prayer books from the Conservative movement that include Selihot?

Tags: prayer-book, selichot, high-holidays

I have been having a surprisingly difficult time finding a copy of selihot prayers.  They appear to not be included in:

*Siddur Sim Shalom* (1985)

*Siddur Sim Shalom for Weekdays* (2002)

*Mahzor Lev Shalem* (2010)

*Mahzor for Rosh Hashanah and Yom Kippur* (1972)

*Weekday Prayer Book* (1965)

Before someone questions why I specifically want a Conservative one, my initial requirement was just that it exist on my bookshelf.  As far as I can tell, selihot are also not in:

*The Complete Artscroll Siddur* (1984)

*Koren Sacks Siddur* (2009)

*Ha-Siddur Ha-Shalem* (Birnbaum 1949)

*Service of the Synagogue - New Year* (Adler 1928)

*Service of the Synagogue - Day of Atonement* (Adler, no date)

*Shilo Prayer Book* (1932)

*Tikun Meir* (1933)

I guess I didn't realize that selihot were that obscure. Are they usually bound in a separate volume?  If am am wrong and overlooked their inclusion in any of the above books, I welcome that answer also.

Answer (score 4):

The text of Selichot which are recited around Rosh Hashanah and Yom Kippur are very lengthy, and are therefore (I presume) usually included in separate standalone volumes. I have seen at least 4 or 5 different Selichot books at my synagogue (including versions published by Artscroll, Koren, etc.), but, like you, have never seen Selichot included in a standard Siddur.

If you'd like a Conservative version, it is available on the Rabbinical Assembly Website [here](https://www.rabbinicalassembly.org/product/selihot).

On the other hand, Selichot for fast days are included in many Siddurim, including some that you checked.

Comment: I can't really assume that anyone would find it useful on MY, but here's a shortened (i.e. only pizmonim) edition used by the Hungarian Neolog community with transliteration. https://www.bzsh.hu/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/Szelichot-Som%c3%a9r-Jiszr%c3%a1%c3%a9l-HU.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Yes they are in a separate volume. for example [ArtScroll](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=selichot+artscroll&ref=nb_sb_noss_1) or [Selichot for the Whole Year Hardcover – June 1, 1956](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/091081810X)

Comment: There is a Conservative version - see my answer below

Comment: @רבותמחשבות I just looked and it is marked out of stock

Comment: How does this answer the question, which seeks Conservative publications?

Comment: @robev "my initial requirement was just that it exist on my bookshelf" seems the OP would be satisfied with non-Conservative options as well

Comment: @DoubleAA then the title could be updated

Comment: @robev it could, but also it's fine since the OP clearly has a preference for Conservative publications. It's ok to specify a preference and an acceptable back up option